# Заполнить массив буквами и цифрами

Tags: массивы, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать строковый массив и заполнить его символами `a-z`, `A-Z` и `0-9`? Просто в ручную это прописывать очень неудобно. И как потом сгенерировать случайный элемент из этого массива?

Comment: @Sergey4590, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Мне надо написать программу которая выводит в файл примерно 10000 комбинаций строковых переменных содержащие эти символы.так вот я придумал определенный алгоритм,как это все будет работать.но я не знаю как создать такой массив без заполнения его вручную.

Comment: У меня ушло примерно 20 секунд, чтобы написать это вручную. Вы уже почти час пытаетесь получить ответ от сообщества.

    final String ALPHABET = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";

Можете не благодарить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ручной ввод и действительно не совсем удобен

Можно сделать так

```
// Создаём и заполняем массив латинских букв
       ArrayList<String> alphaNum = new ArrayList<String>();

       for (char c = 'A';c<= 'z';c++){
           String s = new String();
           s +=c;
           alphaNum.add(s);
           //Исключаем лишние символы ( ],[,...)
           if (c == 'Z') c = 'a'-1;
       }

       for (int c = 0;c<10;c++){
           String s = new String();
           s +=c;
           alphaNum.add(s);
       }
       //Вывод случайного элемента из этого массива
       System.out.println(alphaNum.get((int)(Math.random()*alphaNum.size())));
```

Comment: Тут все замечательно!А можно заместо ассоативного массива использовать обычный строковый массив?И тогда получить случайный элемент этого массива?

Comment: Это не ассоциативный массив. Это коллекция ArrayList (структура данных). Которая как раз и представляет из себя "расширенный массив".
Вам не нужно беспокоиться о его размере (в случае обычного массива он должен быть заранее задан)

Поэтому, на мой взгляд, ArrayList тут намного лучше подходит, чем обычный массив.

Прочитайте еще http://habrahabr.ru/post/128269/

Лишним не будет

Answer (score 3):

Что не удобного в ручном вводе? Создайте строки со всеми буквами и цифрами, а из них уже сформируйте массив символов:

```
    String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String numbers = "0123456789";
    char[] symbols = new char[2*letters.length() + numbers.length()];
    int i = 0;
    for (char letter : letters.toCharArray()) {
        symbols[i] = letter;
        i++;
    }
    for (char letter : letters.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
        symbols[i] = letter;
        i++;
    }
    for (char number : numbers.toCharArray()) {
        symbols[i] = number;
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(symbols);
```

Answer (score 1):

Я вот так делаю:

```
char[] alphabetA = new 
String("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789").toCharArray();
```

И весь код господина Rams666 в одной строке.

Comment: new String() -  не обязательно писать

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае сработает вот такая запись:

```
$array = array_merge(range('a', 'z'),range('A', 'Z'),range('0', '9'));
```