# Как сделать генератор случайных букв?

Tags: java

У меня есть переменная a, типа char, и мне нужно сделать генератор букв, Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Сделайте генератор случайных чисел в пределах от 97 до 122 (юникоды строчных латинских букв от a до z), потом ставьте в соответствие каждому полученному числу букву, через switch case, например. Возможно, простая конвертация типа `char a = (char)97` тоже будет работать.

Comment: У меня просто в генераторе будут и числа, и буквы вот в чем проблема

Comment: Зачем минусовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как вариант - сделать массив типа char, в котором объявить все возможные для генерации символы, и генерировать индекс этого массива.

Не знаю java, напишу на псевдокоде:

```
string dict = "abc...xyz1234567890"; //строка содержит все доступные символы
char c = dict[random % dict.length]; //в переменную с записывается случайный из них
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы генератор выводил числа и буквы по такой формуле a1a1-a1a1-a1a1 где а, там буквы, где 1 там цифры

Comment: Сделайте две строки - с буквами и с цифрами, и через раз выводите из разных строк. Подходит?

Comment: Да блин я не очень шарю

Comment: Можете дать мне программу готовую?

Comment: А все, вроде поняд

Comment: Не понимаю, что тут сложного.
Подучите язык, потом вернётесь к этому вопросу.

Comment: public class Generator {
 char c;
 int b;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  String dict = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //строка содержит все доступные символы
  char c = dict[random % dict.length]; //в переменную с записывается случайный из них 
  
  String dict2 = "123456789"; //строка содержит все доступные символы
  int b = dict2[random % dict2.length]; //в переменную с записывается случайный из них

 }

}

Answer (score 4):

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/217728/java-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=217736#217736) уже разбирался подобный вопрос!

Comment: Я просто не очень хорошо шарю в яве, генератор чисел случайных просто создать, а вот мне нужен отдельный участок кода, который отвечает за то что я написал

Answer (score 2):

```
Random r = new Random();
char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
```

Comment: Можете объяснить?

Answer (score 2):

**upd**: Блин, позорище, перепутал **java** с **javascript**. Ну пусть уж будет.

Написал функцию для генерации случайных элементов по пользовательским словарям.
Посмотреть на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/zPVhq/)** (вывод идет в консоль)

А вот и генератор нужной вам строки на основе этой функции:
Посмотреть на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/GYY2F/1/)** (вывод идет в консоль)

```
// @dict_type - Массив словарей (по умолчанию - латиница)
// Все элементы массива должны быть строкового типа
// В качестве элементов массива могут быть переданы следующие значения:
//    а) Ссылка на один [или несколько] из встроенных словарей
//       Доступны: 'latin', 'cyrillic', 'digits'
//    б) пользовательский словарь (набор [или наборы] любых символов)    
// @length - Длина генерируемой строки (по умолчанию 5 символов)    
// @sensetive - В обоих регистрах? (true | false, по умолчанию - false);
// Функция возвращает сгенерированную строку или false в случае неудачи

function generateSeed(dict_type, length, sensetive) {
    dict_type = typeof dict_type !== 'undefined' ? dict_type : ['latin'];
    length = typeof length !== 'undefined' ? length : 5;
    sensetive = typeof sensetive !== 'undefined' ? !! sensetive : false;
    if (checkArray(dict_type) && typeof length === 'number') {
        var text = "",
            dict = "",
            def = "",
            custom = "",
            possible = [];
        possible.latin = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        possible.cyrillic = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчъыьэюя";
        possible.digits = "0123456789";
        for (j = 0; j < (dict_type.length); ++j) {
            def = possible[dict_type[j]];
            custom = dict_type[j];
            if (typeof def !== 'undefined') {
                dict += (sensetive) ? def + def.toUpperCase() : def;
            } else {
                dict += (sensetive) ? custom + custom.toUpperCase() : custom;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            text += dict.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dict.length));
        }
        return (text === "") ? false : text;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Вспомогательная функция для проверки входного словаря
function checkArray(input) {
    if (input instanceof Array) {
        for (i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
            if (typeof input[i] !== 'string') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Примеры
console.log(generateSeed(['latin', 'cyrillic', 'digits'])); //кuтя6
console.log(generateSeed(['latin', 'cyrillic', 'digits'], 4, true)); //НбIZ
console.log(generateSeed(['latin', 'cyrillic', 'digits'], 4, true)); //RнХф
console.log(generateSeed(['abcde76#()%1123'], 4, true)); //6##(
```

Пример того, как пользоваться моей функцией для генерации нужной вам строки:

```
var key_letters = generateSeed(['latin'], 6).split(""),
    key_digits = generateSeed(['digits'], 6).split(""),
    serial = "";
for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    var delimeter = (i % 2 && i < 5) ? "-" : "";
    serial += key_letters[i]+key_digits[i]+delimeter;
}
console.log(serial); //d0v2-z5i5-v7k2
```

Comment: конечно информативно, но я нуб и называйте меня как хотите, но я не понимаю, если не сложно скиньте готовую программу чтобы был генератор  типа а1а1-а1а1-а1а1 где а - буквы, а 1 - цифры

Comment: @SDsanOk, для "скиньте готовую программу" существуют другие ресурсы, где вы сможете воспользоваться услугами фрилансера и получить желаемый результат не утруждаясь самому.

Comment: Просто, на том уровне знаний которые у меня есть невозможно это сделать, я только изучаю яву

Comment: Вы не изучаете, вы просите, чтобы кто-то предоставил вам готовое решение, то есть выполнил работу за вас. Для этого, как я уже сказал выше, существуют фриланс-биржи. В ответах же вам предоставили уже достаточно рабочих вариантов, которые, даже при наличии минимальных знаний, вы можете самостоятельно подогнать под ваши условия задачи. Было бы желание.

Comment: Так я изучаю яву, но тут ко мне пришла хорошая мысль созздать генератор которыйт многим поможет

Comment: Вы изучаете, вам пришла мысль, а реализовать просите кого-то другого? В чём профит от такого "обучения"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Random r = new Random();
String rus = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчъыьэюя";
String eng = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String dig = "0123456789";
String sum = rus + rus.toUpperCase() +
                 eng + eng.toUpperCase() +
                 dig;
char c = sum.charAt(r.nextInt(sum.length()) );
```